# How do I improve my short VBA code as below?

Tags: vba, excel

I tried to protect cells on my workbook from being edited. I wrote this code,

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Undo
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

But after some tests, I caught an exception. If I cut a cell and paste to another cell, it's ALLOWED! I'm not sure if there are other exceptions like this that I haven't figured out. My question is how do I protect cells being edited but meanwhile able to be copied?

Comment: If the sheet is protected (also the cell you do not want to be changed) then I get an error on ctrl+x (or everything other which would change the cell value).... so which excel do you use?

Comment: I am using Excel 2013. My code can protect me from changing the content of a cell but NOT cut it and paste it into another place. For your solution, how do I protect all the sheets? Seems I have to go to Review>Protect Sheet for each sheet one by one, and this is really troublesome if I have many sheets.@DirkReichel

Comment: Yes, if you use Excel's built-in Protect Sheet, it works fine. But unless there's a solution to apply all sheets at once, I would prefer a short VBA code. However, my current code has some problems.

Answer (score 2):

Use the interface only option, this allows the sheet to be locked - but only for **user** interactions. Any code can interact with the sheet without being blocked:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        ws.Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you please explain a bit about user interaction? What does it include and what does not?

Comment: If a cell is locked, you can not change its contents, but if [Worksheet.Protect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840611.aspx) is **True** then macros still can change it. And as far as I know, for macros the sheet acts like it is not protected without any restrictions.

Comment: Macros can only change it where `Worksheet.Protect` is set to true with the `UserInterfaceOnly` argument. A user interaction is anything that you as a user can change with your keyboard and mouse - the application knows if something was changed by you, or by some code that was running. If it's the letter it will allow that change.

Answer (score 1):

without protecting the sheets the only solution I can think of is:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
  If Application.CutCopyMode = 2 Then Application.CutCopyMode = 0
End Sub
```

Should be self-explaining ;)

or runn all sheets like:

```
Sub protectAllSheets()
  Dim x As Variant
  For Each x In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    x.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
  Next
End Sub
```